# How to make .htaccess work in subfolders with wordpress installed at root

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have my server hosted by Hostgator with multiple domains  like this

at root my main site is installed and i have subfolders by the name of 
web_sites where my other domains are installed  now the problem is  when i am trying to access my subfolders like http://www.xyz.com/subfolder/  it works but when i try to access something like this   http://www.xyz.com/subfolder/category/furniture
now the subfolder also have .htaccess file so it shows me not found page on http://www.xyz.com

that is because  the root .htaccess is not making the inner .htacess file work is there any solution this is my .htaccess file

```
                # BEGIN WordPress
                <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
                 RewriteEngine On
                 RewriteBase /
                 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
                 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
                 RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
                 </IfModule>

                  # END WordPress
```

This is the .htacess inside subfolder

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^home/$ index.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^search_result/$ search_result.php [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^pages/([-A-z0-9]+)/? pages.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^user/([-A-z0-9]+)/? author.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^cms/([-A-z0-9]+)/? cms.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^location_posts/([-A-z0-9]+)/? city.php?city=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^topcat/([-A-z0-9]+)/([-A-z0-9]+)/? categories.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^maincat/([-A-z0-9]+)/([-A-z0-9]+)/? main_categories.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^posts/([-A-z0-9]+)/([-A-z0-9]+)/? post_description.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^special/([-A-z0-9]+)/? special_detial.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^specials_products/$ specials_products.php [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^pricing/$ printing_pricing.php [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^custom_design/$ custom_design.php [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^registration/$ registeration.php [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^portfolio/$ portfolio.php [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^custom_quote/$ custom_quote.php [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^templates/$ templates.php [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^all_templates/$ download_templates.php [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^recent_posts/$ recent_posts.php [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^current_auctions/$ current_auctions.php [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^anil_lal/$ info.php [L,QSA]
```

P.s I tried to find my solutions by searching none is working .

Comment: Can you post `subfolder's .htaccess` code.

Comment: Is there any CMS installed in `subfolder` as well?

Comment: There are man sub domains / websites in that folder so i have to do something with root htacess

Comment: If subfolder has .htaccess then access will be managed by `subfolder/.htaccess` not by root's `.htacess`

Comment: Then why www.xyz.com/subfolder is working but www.xyz.com/subfolder/category/shoes/ goes to the main page displaying nothing found

Comment: `.htaccess` is per directory rules and any sub directory is governed by the its own or its nearest parent's .htaccess

Comment: posting the htacess inside subfolder 
This is the directory structure public_html/mainsite
public_html/mainsite/subfolder/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find a solution it does work but its not satisfactory so i am posting it so it may help ppl

What i did is from  Admin panel of Wordpress Go to

Settings - > Permalinks

Change permalinks to Default

So it will be displaying your wordpress sites as  http://xyz.com/?p=123

but your subfolders websites with pretty urls will work

Stay tune till i find some other solution

Answer (score 0):

Put an explicit exemption for your subdir into the root .htaccess, e.g.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^subfolder
```

Answer (score 0):

this should be :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```